# Simple swift variable to rxswift observable

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Im trying to create an observable from a simple Int so I can subscribe to it upon changing, but it only listens on the first load, what am I missing?

```
private func startObserving() {

    getRating().subscribe(onNext: { (rating: Int) in
        print("NAKO \(rating)")
    })

}

private func getRating() -> Observable<Int> {
    return Observable.create{ observer in
        observer.on(.next(self.ratingView.rating()))
        observer.on(.completed)
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats because you call `observer.on(.completed)` immediately after `observer.on(.next(self.ratingView.rating()))` and all the subscribptions to that specific observable will be removed when u call `observer.on(.completed)` because u have clearly declared that this observable is done emmiting events now you can't call `onNext` further on that onservable

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I removed the ```observer.on(.completed)``` but still Im not getting the latest value

Comment: Thats because that's not how observables are designed to work, if u want to trigger the new value every time u will have to call `observer.on(.next(self.ratingView.rating()))` every time ratingView rating changes inside `Observable.create{` statement. What you actually need here is `Subject` User publishSubject<Int>. Example `let value = PublishSubject<Int>() and trigger the subject every time `self.ratingView.rating()` changes. I believe u have misunderstood how observables work

Comment: because ```self.ratingView.rating()``` is from third party and only return simple Int value, and Im trying to observe if the int value changes

Answer (score 1):

```
// 

var changingValue = PublishSubject<Int>()

// 
// let value = self.ratingView.rating()
// changingValue.onNext(value)           // inform observers like so
//



private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

changingValue.asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (value) in
                print("NAKO \(value)")
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need convert the rating value into stream of values, if you use onCompleted the stream will complete so no need to use onCompleted.

```
let rating = self.ratingView.rating()
Observable.of(rating)
    .subscribe(onNext: { (value: Int) in
        print(value)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you don't have access to modify the original code, the only thing you can do is something like this:

```swift
class YourRatingView: RatingView {
    private let ratingSubject: ReplaySubject<Int>

    override var rating: Int {
        get { return super.rating }
        set { 
            super.rating = newValue
            ratingSubject.on(.next(super.rating))
        }
    }

    override init(){
        ratingSubject = ReplaySubject<Int>.create(bufferSize: 1)
        super.init()
        ratingSubject.on(.next(super.rating))
    }

    var rating_rx: Observable<Int> {
        return ratingSubject.asObservable()
    }
}
```

Look that I'm using a `ReplaySubject` so each time you subscribe you receive at least the last value of rating. Then after each change you will receive an event in your subscription.

### Example of using it:

```
let ratingView = YourRatingView()

ratingView.rating_rx.subscribe(onNext: { rating in
    print(rating)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```